# How to find out whether a LUKS encrypted partition is opened of closed?

Tags: encryption, luks

Which command would you suggest to use in order to find out whether a LUKS encrypted partition is mapped or not (other than looking at or using  `lsblk` output)?

By opened device, I mean a device for which the command

```
ctrytpsetup luksOpen <device> <map name>
```

was executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$ sudo dmsetup ls
    crypthome   (254:0)
$ sudo dmsetup -v table /dev/mapper/crypthome 
    Name:              crypthome
    State:             ACTIVE
    Read Ahead:        256
    Tables present:    LIVE
    Open count:        1
    Event number:      0
    Major, minor:      254, 0
    Number of targets: 1
    UUID: CRYPT-LUKS1-87863643a6aa43c191f69ee3a2b3301a-crypthome
    0 870313984 crypt aes-xts-plain64 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0 8:2 4096
```